# Is wearing pants and shirts allowed?

Tags: sharia, clothing

Is wearing a Shirt and pant where the figure of the body is discernible permissible? I have heard from many of the elders that its haram due to shape visibility. So what is the source for such ruling?

Comment: Are you asking for the ruling on a man or woman?

Comment: men only  @samiles

Answer (score 2):

**In the name of Allah, the most compassionate, the most merciful**

Briefly speaking, as the answer of your query as you asked:

> Is wearing pants and shirts allowed?

According to the verdicts of almost all Maraaje’-Taqlid  of Shia, it is not permissible to wear the mentioned types of clothes. For instance, you can see some of those verdicts in the following link (in Arabic):

- [www.islamquest.net](http://httphttp://islamquest.net/ar/archive/question/fa9335://)